# I want string like this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JSON string array like this:

```
var stringold= [
    {"aptid":1,"businesname":"skulink","ownrnm":"rajiv"},
    {"aptid":2,"businesname":"prodegios","ownrnm":"sanjeev"}
]
```

Please check the below link for detail, what I want to achieve -

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

```
var newstring=[
    ["aptid":1,"businesname":"skulink","ownrnm":"rajiv"],
    ["aptid":2,"businesname":"prodegios","ownrnm":"sanjeev"]
]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.. can you explain it in detail that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question not clear

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear and your `newstring` is not valid Javascript.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's JavaScript. And the second one isn't even valid.

Comment: please chek this link  https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html f but  my string is not in that for as this grid required

Comment: I have *valid array of object*, I want array of *invalidness* - `for detail please chek this link` - that link contains no invalid javascript arrays like you want

Comment: What you want is `[["1", "skulink", "rajiv"],["2","prodegios", "sanjeev"]]` with `columns: [{title: "aptid"},{title:"businesname"},{title:"ownrnm"}]`

Comment: yes sir . i want like that.please give me code for this

Comment: @RajeevKumar ‘*please give me code for this*’ That's not how it works. Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try this iterate through array of object and for 1st object just get the column names as for all its going to be same and for all the objects iterate over it to make data

```js
var stringold= [
{"aptid":1,"businesname":"skulink","ownrnm":"rajiv"},
{"aptid":2,"businesname":"prodegios","ownrnm":"sanjeev"}
]

var columns = [];
var data = [];

//using forEach
/*stringold.forEach(function(ele,ind){ 
  var dummy = [];
  for(var prop in ele){
    if(ind == 0){
      columns.push({title:prop})  
    }
    
    dummy.push(ele[prop]);
  }
  data.push(dummy);
  
});*/

//using loop
for(var i=0;i<stringold.length;i++){ 
  var ele = stringold[i]
  var dummy = [];
  for(var prop in ele){
    if(i == 0){
      columns.push({title:prop})  
    }
    
    dummy.push(ele[prop]);
  }
  data.push(dummy);
  
};
console.log(columns,data);
```

Comment: getting error :  0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

Comment: which browser you are using ? forEach over array is an advance JS if foreach is giving u problemns change it to for(var i=o;i<stringold.length;i++){ var ele = stringold[i] ... same code block} code edited with loop

Comment: chrome,mozilla.ie

Comment: make sure stringold exists and is an array of object as in que or try for loop that will makes thing clear what was  missing before

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the objects and then the keys of the object and map the values.

```js
var arrayOld = [{ aptid: 1, businesname: "skulink", ownrnm: "rajiv" },{ aptid: 2, businesname: "prodegios", ownrnm: "sanjeev" }],
    arrayNew = arrayOld.map(function (o) {
        return Object.keys(o).map(function (k) {
            return o[k];
        });
    });

console.log(arrayNew);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```